# Send KeyBoardKeys to another aplication launched on the same project

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I am trying to send some keyboard keys to control a game boy advance emulator launched on the same project, but it doesnt find the process

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr point);

    ///////////////////////

    /// <summary>
    /// Method used to run VisualBoyAdvance emulator with a GBA ROM
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command"></param>
    public void RunProgram()
    {

        // PATH of the ROM
        const string ex1 = @"C:\GameBoy\marioKart.gba";

        // Use ProcessStartInfo class
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        //Name of the emulator, PATH
        startInfo.FileName = @"C:\GameBoy\VisualBoyAdvance-SDL.exe";

        //Can be set to hidden to hide.
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        //Arguments if needed
        startInfo.Arguments ="  " + ex1;
    try
    {

            // Start the process with the info we specified.
            // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
            using (Process execProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                //Select the process to send the keys

                Process[] localAll = Process.GetProcesses();
                Process p = localAll[0];
                Console.WriteLine(p);
                if( p != null)
                {
                    IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
                    SetForegroundWindow(h);
                    //Sending some "Enter" keys
                    SendKeys.SendWait("~");
                    SendKeys.SendWait("~");
                    SendKeys.SendWait("~");
                    SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                }
                execProcess.WaitForExit();


            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.Write("~");
            Console.Write("Error.");
        }

    }
```

I dont know if I am not sending the keys right or whatever. Thank you guys!

Comment: Is it possible that the keys are being sent too rapidly, before the process finishes opening? Perhaps you'd want to introduce a small delay between the opening of the process and the sending of the keys.

Comment: i have just tried this and it doesnt work: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)

Comment: Instead of using `Thread.Sleep`, try `p.WaitForInputIdle()`. Put it right before `IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unklikely that your keys are being sent to the correct process `localAll[0]`.  Make sure you are sending them to the right application (e.g. `Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.ProcessName == "VisualBoyAdvance-SDL")` or `Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("VisualBoyAdvance-SDL")`. Make sure check for a 0 length array in the first case or null in the second.

Other than that, using SendKeys.SendWait should work for you as this is essentially the Win32 API SendMessage (SendKeys.Send would use the Win32 API PostMessage).

Comment: Also see the [following](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx) from MSDN:   The SendKeys class has been updated for the .NET Framework 3.0 to enable its use in applications that run on Windows Vista. The enhanced security of Windows Vista (known as User Account Control or UAC) prevents the previous implementation from working as expected...